# Dynamic height of my OHAttributedLabel

Tags: ios

I am using the Custom UILabel class `OHAttributedLabel` to display my text as JUSTFIED  . After my `OHAttributedLabel` i want to display  a `UIButtton` . How to get the Dynamic height of my `OHAttributedLabel` . I tried many ways that found in stackoverflow itself. Unfortunately none of the methods are giving me the correct Height . Help me to fox this issue ......

Answer (score 7):

Hi I am the author of OHAttributedLabel.
Thanks for using it.

Did you try to use sizeToFit an sizeThatFits: methods? sizeThatFits: is a UIView method (that I override in OHAttributedLabel) that gives you the ideal size of the view/label depending on it's content.

You can also use my NSAttributedString+Attributes addition to compute the size of you NSAttributedString in pixels (I recently added a method in the header for that, and actually sizeThatFits call it)

HTH